# How to simplify conditional array value addition

Tags: javascript, arrays, dry, ternary-operator, repeat

Here is the code:

```
const presets = (buildType === "___PROD___") ?
                        [   "react",
                            "es2015",
                            { "modules" : false }
                        ] : [
                            "react",
                            "es2015"
                        ];
```

As can be see, the values of `react`, `es2015` are being repeated. Is it possible to not have this repetition in the ternary operator?

Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)?

```
var standardPresets = ['react','es2015'];
const presets = cond ? [ ...standardPresets , {modules: false} ] : [ ...standardPresets ];
```

Does you have to use a ternary `if`? Could you just `.push` into the array when that condition is met?

```
const standardPresets = ['react','es2015'];
if(cond){ standardPresets.push({modules: false}); }
```

Personally, I don't think the repetition is too awful as it is.

Comment: Beer o'clock it is :) np. I like your answer though, was thinking of a similar solutions myself.